# Does $\binom{n}{k}$ additions or XORs run in polynomial time?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

If $O(\binom{n}{k})$ = $O(min(n^k, n^{n-k}))$, does that mean a function that runs $\binom{n}{k}$ iterations (e.g. additions, XORs) runs in polynomial time?

I keep arguing myself in circles whether it does or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parameters here, $n$ and $k$. So you can't just say that the algorithm runs in polynomial time unless you can say *what* it's polynomial in. Although it's hard to say that it's polynomial in $k$ because $k$ is restricted to being no greater than $n$, so you can't just let $k$ go to infinity on its own.

For any constant value of $k$, it is true that ${n \choose k} = O(n^k)$, and so the algorithm is polynomial in $n$.

Similarly, for any constant difference $n - k = m$, it's true that ${n \choose k} = O(n^m)$, and so the algorithm is again polynomial in $n$.

However, consider what happens if we're always at the midpoint - so $k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. In this case ${n \choose k} = O(n^{\frac{n}{2}}) = O(\exp(\frac{n}{2}\log n))$ which is factorial complexity.

Comment: I have a specific problem in mind that takes two inputs, a square truth table of size $p^2$ and a value $k$ and iterates over $p^2$, looking for a certain pattern of size $k$. I've got several techniques for minimizing the search space on any given iteration by ruling out and excluding chunks of $p$.  But while $k$ is fixed, the $n$ in $\binom{n}{k})$ is variable, which means that while $k \leq p$, I can't guarantee $k \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: … So it sounds like I need to be able to guarantee that $k$ is always either huge or tiny w.r.t $p$, right?

Comment: If you're looking at different values of $k$ then $k$ is *not* fixed. You can describe the behaviour for any single fixed value of $k$ as being polynomial in $n$, but as long as the possible values of $k$ vary depending on $n$ you're almost certainly going to be getting factorial behaviour.

Comment: I'm typing on my phone, so it sounds like you're replying to one of my several comments that were sunbird and then deleted mid-edit — sorry!

To clarify, $k$ is fixed but $n$ is variable, and I'm working on ways of limiting $n$. Is it always the case that for a fixed $k$ and $m < n$, $\binom{m}{k} < \binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: It is true that ${m \choose k} < {n \choose k}$, because the ways to choose $k$ objects out of $n$ is going to include all the ways to choose them out of $m$, plus additional ones. However, I think you need to carefully review what "polynomial time" means because it's only used in reference to the size of the input as that size grows without bound and it's not clear to me which value out of $n, p, k$ is the one that you're trying to vary.

Comment: Ah. I'm developing a generalized algorithm that includes looking for patterns where there are $k$ `true` values in the rows of a truth table of size $p^2$. If a row doesn't have at least $k$ `true` values, it can't contain the pattern and can be ignored. The pattern can be hard to spot because the rows and columns are not in a predictable order. Taking that into account requires $O(\binom{n}{k}) | n \subseteq p, k \leq n$ time. I'm pretty sure that means the time complexity of the whole problem should be stated in terms of $p$, but I'm just asking about the complexity of this one part for now.

Comment: Then it is reasonable to just say that ${n \choose k\} = O(n^k)$, i.e. it is polynomial in $n$ but exponential in $k$, meaning that for any single fixed value of $k$ it is indeed polynomial complexity, but across all allowable values of $k$ its is factorial in $n$ since the worst-case scenario happens at $k = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. If you're looking at embedding this inside another algorithm that is, for example, looping over values of $k$, then I'd just leave it as being $O(n^k)$ because that will probably be relevant in the loop.